# How to create a directory in the current directory in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mkdir

I am new to Node.js, so I'm not familiar with a lot of stuff.
So basically I want to create a directory in the current working directory:

```
 var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
 console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
 mkdirp('/tmp/test',function(err){
       if (err) {
           return console.error(err);
        }
console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

My current directory is `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Tutorials\NodeJS` on Windows, which means I run `node main.js` in that directory.
(main.js is in `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Tutorials\NodeJS`)
After I run the code, it generates C:\tmp\test, which is in `C:\`.
But I want to create it in the current directory, so the result I want is `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Tutorials\NodeJS\tmp\test`.

I just don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `process.cwd()` to output the directory where your command has been executed (in your case, the directory where you run `node main.js`) so your code might look like this:

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var path = require('path');

console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
mkdirp(path.join(process.cwd(), '/tmp/test'), function(err){
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

If you need just the directory where the `main.js` file is located and not where you execute it (by calling `node main.js`), you can use the `__dirname` variable instead of `process.cwd()`.

It's a good idea to use the `path.join()` function to make sure the path delimiters are set correctly, especially when you're on a Windows system which may treat forward slashes as options.

Comment: awesome, that's exactly what I want, and it works...just one thing, there's a syntax error in the code block. Thanks.  path.join(process.cwd(), '/tmp/test') only need one ) at the end...

Answer (score -1):

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var path = require('path');
console.log("Going to create directory /tmp/test");
mkdirp(path.join(__dirname, '/tmp/test'),function(err){
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log("Directory created successfully!");
});
```

You could use `path.join(__dirname, '/tmp/test')` where `__dirname` would return `The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.`

You need to include module 'path' to make `path.join()` work.

**Reference**

[__dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)

Comment: This is wrong. `__dirname` will return the absolute path to the directory where `main.js` is placed, but not where it is executed.

Comment: My bad in understanding certain concepts, but I executed this code in my local machine and verified that it creates the directory as the OP wants

Comment: It does that only because of this specific example where the file is located in the same directory as it is run, which is an edge case. Technically, your answer is wrong.